# Android to Windows Socket File Transfer Through Browser

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I am trying to transfer a file from Android device to Windows PC. I get the ip and the port used by the browser. I want to send the file in a way so that the browser will show the user the save file prompt. The current code I am using is like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);

socket.setSoTimeout(1000*10);

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
writer.write("Hello World!");
writer.flush();
writer.close();

socket.close();
```

I get `ConnectionException` (timeout).

Of course, I am open for suggestions for ways that would make this possible, or easier.

Thanks a lot in advance!